# Xcode with PVCS

Tags: xcode, integration, pvcs, serena

Just curious if anyone have worked with PVCS and Xcode? I am trying to access SCM and wanted to make sure if it's even supported.

Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific. Are you talking about the (horrible) PVCS version control software? And what do you mean by "supported"? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Neil, Yes I am talking about the EVIL PVCS version control, now I sense serene ChangeMan Control is what the new name is. I mean by support like can I upload files through XCode via PVCS? I want to upload all my repositories, and my company is using serena ChangeMan. Neil, sorry for not making it so clear, so any 2cents here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't be more helpful. Me and PVCS parted company on a Sun box over 10 years ago. And Polytron once tried to headhunt me, but I told them where to go.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your updates, I am thinking of using SVN for my project now.

Answer (score 0):

PVCS is not supported on OS X. The closest thing you can get is:

> If you have access to a Linux machine, you can install VM on the Linux box. Create an NFS mount (in Snow Leopard this is done in Disk Utility). You could then do an SSH session allowing remote X-Windows so that you can invoke VM on the Linux box and see it displayed on your Mac. The NFS mount will allow you to write the archive to what would appear to be a local directory on your Mac (it wouldn't be local, however, so I would recommend having a Folder Action that copies any file written to your mounted directory to, say, your Desktop).
>
> If you have a Windows machine, you could install VM on the Windows machine and then using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) connect to your Windows box. You could also remotely mount a directory on your Windows machine and, again, have a Folder Action that copies the checked out file to your desktop.

**References**

- [Install PVCS on a linux virtual machine](http://communities.serena.com/serena/topics/is_there_anyway_to_access_a_pvcs_database_from_macos)
- [Remote X11 GUI for Linux/Unix | Red Wire Services](https://www.redwireservices.com/remote-x11-for-linux-unix)
- [Setup ssh in XCode](http://ricardo-dias.com/2012/01/08/developing-for-linux-under-os-x-in-xcode/)